# Criar paginas com diferentes parametros e depois acessa-lá

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade: estou tentando criar uma plataforma de EAD básica onde caso o usuário tenha permissão ele consiga enviar um vídeo do vimeo; colocar uma descrição e *katchaw*

No caso após ele enviar que vem minha verdadeira duvida de como fazer, acima eu estou guardando tudo no banco de dados; minha verdadeira questão é como listar um novo vídeo quando adicionado na pagina principal e depois como recuperar esses parâmetros do vídeo da db e assim reproduzir a pagina enviada pelo usuario

Questão resumida: quero listar os videos enviados recentes em uma unica pagina; assim como o YouTube faz. você envia e o video mais recente ocupa uma area na homepage

Comment: Com a cláusula `order by ... desc` do SQL você consegue listar os últimos registros conforme os dados de uma coluna. Mas como você tentou fazer? O que pesquisou antes de fazer a pergunta?

Comment: você pode criar um campo no registro com o nome "data_de_upload" e fazer sua validação a partir daí...caso o video tenha o "data_de_upload" com diferença de 3 dias (exemplo) ele é exibido como recente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu ainda não tentei fazer essa parte justamente por não ter ideia como xD, Porém fiz no banco de dados os ids de postagem

Comment: Alguém? preciso de ajuda :(